# Bootstrap 3: nested columns stacked on desktop, inline on mobile

Tags: html, css, sql, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to nest columns in the following way:

For a desktop view, you should see LONG COLUMN 1 on the left, LONG COLUMN 2 in the middle, and then SHORT COLUMN 1 on the top right with SHORT COLUMN 2 and SHORT COLUMN 3 stacked beneath it.

For a tablet view, you should see LONG COLUMN 1 at full width, then LONG COLUMN 2 at full width below that, then SHORT COLUMN 1, SHORT COLUMN 2 & SHORT COLUMN 3 stacked next to each other below LONG COLUMN 2.

Here is a sketch of how I am hoping it will look (sorry for messy drawing): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrXvX.jpg

I've tried the code below but it's stacking SHORT COLUMN 1-3 next to each other on both views.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers, Charlie

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                LONG COLUMN 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                LONG COLUMN 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        SHORT COLUMN 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        SHORT COLUMN 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        SHORT COLUMN 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to give the long columns col-sm-12. Then give the other div col-sm-4.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"></div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> 
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

You can add the xs class for more fine tuning too.

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly. A higher understanding of the grid has just clicked for me... Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, bootstrap is awesome.